# Zabbix 3.0 - Como receber dados de associação de rádio via SNMP

Tags: zabbix

Sou novato na plataforma Zabbix e conheço muito pouco sobre o protocolo SNMP.

Minha pergunta é simples, vai a explicação do processo:

1 - Cada estação do metrô possui 2 rádios (1 em cada via) e cada trem possui seu próprio rádio;

2 - Quando um trem chega na estação, ele associa e autentica com o respectivo rádio na via da estação em questão, aparecendo a informação abaixo (usando o comando Telnet no rádio da estação, consigo observar esses dados de conexão):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Na imagem, mostra um MAC ADRESS autenticado e associado, ou seja, nada mais é que o trem X está na estação Y.

Pergunta: Preciso de uma forma simples de como posso fazer o Zabbix me enviar via SNMP as seguintes informações no ATO da conexão (assim que o trem autentica):

- MAC ADRESS da conexão (no caso o Trem);
- MAC ADRESS do rádio (no caso a estação e via em questão);
- Data e Hora da conexão;

Obs: Pretendo ter esses MAC ADRESS em um banco de dados para saber qual o nome do trem e nome da estação, que será feito posteriormente.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Bom, primeiramente você precisa compreender que o zabbix não envia informação alguma via SNMP, muito pelo contrário, ele consegue capturar informações que o seu dispositivo (rádio) disponibiliza via SNMP.

Para saber tudo o que seu rádio disponibiliza, você deve utitlizar o snmpwalk para efetuar as consultas no equipamento e posteriormente contruir a monitoração atráves do zabbix.

Não esquece de sempre consultar a documentação oficial do zabbix.

Abaixo alguns links que irão te ajudar no processo.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/
https://www.4linux.com.br/o-que-e-snmp

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Bons estudos.